# NP-complete problems with aperiodic Wang tiles

Tags: np-complete, tiling

Consider the problem of tiling a rectangular region with a given set of [Wang tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile). It is well-known that this problem is NP-complete: every NP problem can be encoded as some form of tiling problem (see e.g. [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/301663721.pdf)). It is also well-known that there are particular sets of tiles that only tile the plane aperiodically. The smallest tile set which does so is given [here](https://www.advancesincombinatorics.com/article/18614-an-aperiodic-set-of-11-wang-tiles).

I am interested if there are any NP-complete problems that can be formulated with a set of tiles which tiles the plane only aperiodically (note that here I am *fixing* a particular tile set).

For example, given one such aperiodic tile set, is it possible to tile a square region with fixed boundary conditions? Or, as an optimization problem, what is the smallest number of `mistakes' that can be made in an approximate tiling of such a region? Could any of these two problems be NP-complete / hard?